# How to get disqus comments iframe data using Selenum WebDriver

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, iframe, disqus

I have been trying to use Selenium WebDriver (Chrome) to load a page and get disqus comment threads. Please see the code.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://nation.com.pk/blogs/05-Apr-2016/should-qandeel-baloch-s-strip-tease-really-be-a-rallying-cause-for-liberalism");
            var userNameField = driver.FindElementById("disqus_thread").GetAttribute("outerHTML");
            Console.WriteLine(userNameField);
            Console.Read();
        }
```

It gives the following output.

```
<div id="disqus_thread"><iframe id="dsq-app2" name="dsq-app2" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" tabindex="0" title="Disqus" width="100%" src="http://disqus.com/embed/comments/?base=default&amp;version=af1a2e2611136ef6c314afec2806cef3&amp;f=nawaiwaqt&amp;t_u=http%3A%2F%2Fnation.com.pk%2Fblogs%2F05-Apr-2016%2Fshould-qandeel-baloch-s-strip-tease-really-be-a-rallying-cause-for-liberalism&amp;t_d=Should%20Qandeel%20Baloch%E2%80%99s%20%E2%80%98striptease%E2%80%99%20really%20be%20a%20rallying%20cause%20for%20liberalism%3F&amp;t_t=Should%20Qandeel%20Baloch%E2%80%99s%20%E2%80%98striptease%E2%80%99%20really%20be%20a%20rallying%20cause%20for%20liberalism%3F&amp;s_o=default" style="width: 1px !important; min-width: 100% !important; border: none !important; overflow: hidden !important; height: 652px !important;" horizontalscrolling="no" verticalscrolling="no"></iframe></div>
```

Which is contrary to my expectations as I was hoping to get comments html at this stage. How can I modify this code to get the comment thread?
PS: there is no indication of iframe in original page source.

Comment: did you consider checking the url for the iframe?

Comment: Could you please elaborate. How can I check the url for iframe?
I have also (by reading other help posts) figured out that to interact with an iframe, the driver element must switch to iframe. What I am not sure is, how can this change this fact that there is no comment thread shown in this output.

Comment: because the content is within an iframe supplied from another domain

Comment: Ok. I got an idea. The focus is shifted to iframe. And then i was able to extract the page source (iframe source actually). It is a dirty method but I can save these files one by one and then process them with HtmlAgilityPack to get comments within. I am updating the code above.

Answer (score 1):

So here is how I could get the iframe source code for further processing. Hope it helps someone else.

```
var driver = new ChromeDriver();
            int tmp = 1;
            foreach(string file in File.ReadLines(@"bla bla bla\Bloglinks.txt"))
            {
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(file);
                driver.SwitchTo().Frame("dsq-app2");
                var userNameField = driver.PageSource;
                File.WriteAllText(@"bla bla bla\Comments\"+tmp+".html", userNameField);
                Console.WriteLine(file);
                tmp++;
            }
            driver.Close();
```